# Temporary users

Tags: discussion, new-users

I see a lot of new/temporary users coming and going through this site, often posting incomplete or nonsensical questions that just can't be answered for one reason or another, like [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183071/please-help-me-forge-wont-work).

Now by my understanding, (it's been a while since I first started here) the best we can do is just spam their emails a bit until they relent and check the link to see what's going on.

Is that really the best we can do though? What exactly do we send these temp users? Just answers or do we send them notifications when they get comments as well? The question above may be a legitimate question, it may be a dupe, but we'll never know until the user gets the urge to come back and check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am really not sure what the problem is. They don't have to come back. It would be nice if they did come and clarify or what have you, but there is no requirement, and it doesn't hurt us any - downvote, vote to close, comment, and move on. The only one they are hurting by not coming and giving us the info they need is themselves - it really has no bearing on the site.

Comment: Hmm... putting into that perspective kinda makes me realise it's just frustrating on my part. I love answering questions because when I come across a question I want to answer, I go into research mode. But when I see a question that can't be answered, it yanks the reins. *humph*

Comment: Yeah, it is most certainly not the most fun experience ever.

Answer (score 4):

Eh, there really isn't anything we can do. Particularly if they (as they often don't) didn't provide any sort of email address, or didn't check the box asking to receive email notifications of new answers or comments. Remember, to ask a question on Stack Exchange *registration is not required*.

If they don't come back, they don't come back. Part of what makes the whole idea of SE so great is that good questions stay here to help anyone else who happens to come through, even if the person who originally asked the question never comes back to see the answer.